# Strange behavior of facet_grid()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just met a strange behavior of `facet_grid()` in ggplot2 0.9, and I wonder if someone could explain it to me...

Take the following `df` data frame :

```
var <- sample(c("red", "blue"), 100, replace=TRUE)
group <- sample(c("group1", "group2"), 100, replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(var=factor(var), group=factor(group))
```

Which looks like :

```
  var  group
1 red group2
2 red group1
3 red group1
4 red group2
5 red group2
6 red group1
```

If I draw a bar chart of `var` faceted by `group`, I get a rather strange set of y-values :

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=var)) + geom_bar() + facet_grid(~group)
```

[image: plot1]

It seems strange because the y-values seem correct if I use `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid` :

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=var)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image: plot2]

Moreover, I can get back correct values with `facet_grid` if I introduce another dummy variable in the data frame :

```
df$tmp <- 1:nrow(df)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=var)) + geom_bar() + facet_grid(~group)
```

[image: plot3]

So, is it some sort of bug, or a normal behavior that I didn't understand?

Comment: This is a bug. see this discussion: https://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/5213ac35da6b36d4

Comment: Shouldn't it be `facet_grid(.~group)` rather than `facet_grid(~group)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has been in fixed in version 0.9.1 of ggplot2.